# Android - How is it possible, that a service keeps running after the Activity has been shut down?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I am a bit confused about how services function, notably these two things:

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html :

> A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.

and:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise).

My questions:

1. How is it possible for a service that was started by startService() survive, if the main Activity thread quits? Or only those services survive the main Activity shutdown, that are in a separate thread?
2. How can I start a service in a separate thread? The dev doc at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#ExtendingService only shows an example how to spawn a thread when the service is created...not how to spawn the service itself in a new thread...
   EDIT: Is `android:process=` in manifest.xml used for starting it in a separate thread? (if it starts it in a new process, then it must be in a separate thread..)

Comment: @Kiran i'll accept, if my second question is answered too. See my edit about a guess how to solve it.

Comment: Usually you spawn threads to distribute the load. But the purpose of a Service itself is to perform some heavy operations without interfering with Activity. Answer this question: "Can you start an Activity on a separate thread?". In all probability, the same answer is applicable to a Service as well

Comment: Service is a macro component of Android platform. And a Thread is a micro element of the Virtual Machine. A Service can spawn threads and control them within it's context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote you,:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise).

When the main activity is shutdown, it does not necessarily mean the hosting process exits. According to the documentation, the service continues to run because the process is alive!

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle)

> The Android system will attempt to keep the process hosting a service around as long as the service has been started or has clients bound to it. When running low on memory and needing to kill existing processes, the priority of a process hosting the service will be the higher

So on only when running low on resources and it is required to kill processes lying around, your process would be killed. Else. the process lives on so would your service.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my first question perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

1. A started service can survive the shutdown of an activity that starts it in exactly the same way that one activity can survive the shutdown of another activity that starts it with `startActivity()`. Activities and services are just two separate components of your application process. Once started, each exists independently of the other. (Things are a bit different with bound services — the system will shut down a bound service when nothing is bound to it anymore.)
2. You cannot start a service in a separate thread, any more than you can start an activity in a non-event thread. You can only ask the system to start the service (via `startService()` or `bindToService()`). The system always starts the service on the event thread.

Comment: and what happens if i specify android:process=":remote" for my service in the manifest.xml? It will still be on the same thread?

Comment: @sydd - If you specify a process name like that, it will indeed run in a separate thread because it will be in a separate process. The service will still run in the event thread of that other process, however, so you still need to write the service accordingly (putting time-consuming work into a worker thread).

Comment: @Todd Are you sure, it will run in the event thread? if i make a service with its own `android:process`, and put a `wait(5000)` inside its messenger's `handleMessage()` method, it wont block the UI thread.  But if i remove the `android:process` declaration, the wait command blocks the UI thread.

Comment: @sydd - it runs in the event thread of the other process. The service won't be responsive to incoming requests until the `wait` is over. But you are correct that it won't block the UI thread of another process.

Comment: Thanks, now i understand everything. Its a pity, that i cant choose 2 correct answers :(